# Get all files and directories in current directory python

Tags: python, file, package

I am writing a python package manager, and I am making it so that it generates the `__all__` object based on the programs/packages in the current directory, but I also want to ignore any non-packages.
i.e, if I had the following directory structure:

```
project
|------__init__.py
|------prog1.py
|------package
    |------__init__.py
    |------prog2.py
|------resources
    |------ping.png
```

I want the `__all__` variable to be the following:

```
__all__ = ['prog1', 'package']
```

I have tried various things, but in all honesty, I have no idea what I'm doing.

This is what I tried last:

```
import os
from os import path


def config_all(directory):
    __all__ = []
    directory = path.abspath(directory)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        for d in dirs:
            os.chdir("/czar/".join(path.abspath(d).rsplit("/", 1)))
            v = list(os.walk('.'))[0][2]
            if "__init__.py" in v:
                __all__.append(d)
            for i in v:
                while i in __all__:
                    __all__.remove(i)
            os.chdir('..')
        for f in files:
            __all__.append(path.join(root, f).rsplit("/", 1)[1].rsplit(".", 1)[0])
    return __all__

__all__ = config_all('czar/')
print(__all__)
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and what documentation you've read.

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't show what I have tried yet because it did not work nearly as I wanted it to, and I didn't want the responses on this post to be tangential.

Comment: Don't do this: don't make `__all__` dynamic. Simply *explicitly* specify which functions and variables you want to be exported from a module.

Comment: Note that `__all__` doesn't even work for modules and subpackages in a package, so what you are trying to do won't work anyway.

Comment: @script8man: May I ask you to comment each line after `for d in dirs:`?

Comment: never use `os.chdir`. It's not thread safe.

Comment: This is all crazy advice... I didn't even know all of this... 

Answer (score 1):

You want all .py-files and all directories with a `__init__.py` file of the given directory, use `glob`:

```
def config_all(directory):
    result = []
    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*', '__init__.py')):
        result.append(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filename))
    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.py'):
        result.append(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0])
    return result
```